# How probable is that two exact same calculations give different results?

Tags: numbers

I am currently working on remaking an old invoicing program that was originally written in VB6.
It has two parts, one on an android tablet, the other on a pc. The old database used , stored derived values because there was a chance that the calculations would be incorrect if repeated.
For example if one sold 5 items whose price was 10 euros at 10% discount and a tax value of 23% , it would store the above 4 values but also the result of the calucation of (5 * (10 * 1.23)) * 0.9.
I do not really like having duplicate or derivable information in my database, but the actual sell value must be the same, whether it is viewed on a tablet , or a pc.
So my question is , is there a chance (even the slightest one) that the above calucation (to a three decimal percision) would have different results on different operating systems (such as an android device and a desktop computer) ?
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Floating-point arithmetic is always subject to rounding errors and different languages (and architectures) deal with those errors in different ways. There are best practices in dealing with these issues, though I don't consider myself knowledgeable enough to speak to them. But here are a couple of options for you.

1. Use a data type meant for floating-point arithmetic. For example, VB6 has a Single and Double type for floating point but also a Currency type for accurate decimal math.
2. Scale your floating-point values to integers and perform your calculations on these integer values. You can even store the results as integers in your DB. The ERP system we use does this and includes a data dictionary that defines how each type was scaled so that it can be "unscaled" before display.

Hope that helps.